# R: How to merge logical elements in a list

Tags: r, list, reduce

I have data like the following

```
set.seed(1)
glist <- lapply(1:5,function(i){sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),1)})
```

I would like the index locations of the FALSE values, c(3,4).  I am trying to coerce the list array into an array with

```
tf_array <- Reduce(merge,glist)
```

the output is

```
[1] y x
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

the output I was expecting is below, and then I was going to use the which function.

```
c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE).
```

How do I locate the indices of the FALSE entries in a list of logical values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unlist(glist)` gives the output you're expecting:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then, using `which()`:

```
which(!unlist(glist))
# [1] 3 4
```